# RabbitMQ - Ruby - Bunny - Best practise to (re-)publish messages to next queue

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

we are checking RabbitMQ for some Workflow use case.

So far, we created a test environment with ruby which fits our needs and seems to work fine.

The question I have, in case of being Rabbit newbies, is about best / good practise.

Lets define 3 QUEUES (just for the example)

1. Q_DECISION
2. Q_RIGHT
3. Q_LEFT

every producer will post message inside Q_DECISION

There is a worker running on that queue which check some content of the body. In case of decision, the message / task has to be moved to Q_LEFT or Q_RIGHT.

We are storing message specific information properties.headers, so we repeat them as well as the body.

So far no problem, question is now about republishing:

```ruby
q_decision.subscribe(:block => true) do |delivery_info, properties, body|

  # ... more code here

  if (decision_left)

    q_left.publish(body, :headers => properties.headers, :persistent => true)

  end

end
```

If we do re-publishing like above, do we loose something from the previous message?

There are a lot of attributes defined / stored in `delivery_info` and `properties` as well.

Do we have to re-post them or only the self created headers and body?

Comment: Why not just put all the info you need in the body?

Comment: Using the headers will automatically encode all values. If you want to do this with body you have to solve that by your own. But wherever to store "private" values, my question is: What kind of attributes should be re-published in general.

Comment: That depends heavily on your needs.  What information do you actually need when you pull the message off the queue?

Comment: For our solution we are just looking for the `body` and two arrays we added to headers as `properties.headers['data']`and `properties.headers['ctx']`. My question is to know, what kind attribute must be re-published like: id (surely not) or timestamp or will those attributes always generated new by th re-publish action? In that case we are fine just with body and headers.

Comment: In my usage, when moving a message from one queue to another (don't forget to ack the original), I republished the body and let bunny do whatever it wanted with everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Message body and message headers are two different things. I would assume bunny or any client library will create a new message with the body you are passing. This means you need to re-set the headers you want to pass to the next queue as well.

Comment: Question was: Do we need to repost some of the **OTHER** defined properties like described here:

**Extract:**

RabbitMQ messages have various metadata attributes that can be set when a message is published. Some are well-known and mentioned in AMQP, others are specific to a particular application. Well-known attributes are:

    :persistent
    :mandatory
    :timestamp
    :expiration
    :type
    :reply_to
    :content_type
    :content_encoding
    :correlation_id
    :priority
    :user_id
    :app_id

All other attributes can be added to a headers table:

Comment: Unless you use the same message instance, I would assume you need to repost everything. By message instance I mean the Ruby object that represents the message.